# C program to check balanced parentheses

Tags: c, arrays, data-structures, stack

This is my program to check the balancing of parentheses. It is showing no error and no warning but it is not showing exact output that it should show.

NOTE I am little bit sure that I may have error in my `checkBalanced` function

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Stack
{
    int top;
    int capacity;
    int *array;
};

struct Stack *createstack(int capacity)
{
    struct Stack *stack = (struct Stack *)malloc(sizeof(struct Stack));
    if (!stack)
        return NULL;
    stack->top = -1;
    stack->capacity = capacity;

    stack->array = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * stack->capacity);
    if (!stack->array)
        return NULL;
    return stack;
}

// to check whether the stack is empty

int isempty(struct Stack *stack)
{
    return stack->array[stack->top--];
}

char pop(struct Stack *stack)
{
    return stack->array[stack->top--];
}

void push(struct Stack *stack, char exp)
{
    stack->array[++stack->top] = exp;
}

// returns the peak value of stack

char peek(struct Stack *stack)
{
    return stack->array[stack->top];
}

// function to check the correct matching of paranthesis at stack top and exp[i]

int ismatchingpair(char char1, char char2)
{
    if (char1 == '(' && char2 == ')')
        return 1;
    if (char1 == '[' && char2 == ']')
        return 1;
    if (char1 == '{' && char2 == '}')
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

// function to check balancing of paranthesis

int checkBalanced(char *exp)
{
    struct Stack *stack = createstack(strlen(exp));
    if (!stack)
        return NULL;

    for (int i = 0; exp[i]; ++i)
    {
        if (exp[i] == '(' || exp[i] == '{' || exp[i] == '[')
            push(stack, exp[i]);
        else if (exp[i] == ')' || exp[i] == '}' || exp[i] == ']')
        {
            if (isempty(stack) || !ismatchingpair(peek(stack), exp[i]))
                return -1;
            else
                pop(stack);
        }
    }
    printf("parenthesis are balanced");
}

// main function

int main()
{
    char exp[50] = "(){}";

    checkBalanced(exp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the best friend in this case is your debugger/some debug prints. Code debugging questions need to be _focused_ on Stackoverflow

Comment: Having made a basic edit on the code posted to convert "quoted" sections to code comments, I was able to copy/paste and compile. MSVC gives two warnings, 1) test.c(64): warning C4047: 'return': 'int' differs in levels of indirection from  'void *' and 2) test.c(82) : warning C4715: 'checkBalanced': not all control paths return a value.

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue is with your `isempty()` function.Your `isempty()` is returning some value , that won't work on your `if-condition` , `if (isempty(stack) || !ismatchingpair(peek(stack), exp[i]))`. A function for if-condition should `return` either `0` or `1`.

Modify it to :-

```
int isempty(struct Stack *stack)
{
    if (stack->top == -1)
        return 1;

    return 0;
}
```

Output :-

```
parenthesis are balanced
```

Also make sure that `int checkBalanced(char *exp)` return `int` values. **NULL** is not integer, It is pointer.

Recommended to modify it to :-

```
int checkBalanced(char *exp)
{

    struct Stack *stack = createstack(strlen(exp));
    if (!stack)
        return 0; // not NULL

    for (int i = 0; exp[i]; ++i)
    {
        if (exp[i] == '(' || exp[i] == '{' || exp[i] == '[')
            push(stack, exp[i]);
        else if (exp[i] == ')' || exp[i] == '}' || exp[i] == ']')
        {
            if (isempty(stack) || !ismatchingpair(peek(stack), exp[i]))
                return -1;

            else
                pop(stack);
        }
    }
    printf("parenthesis are balanced");
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Good catch, looks like a copy/paste error from the identical next funtion `pop()`.

Comment: Thank u very much @anoopknr sir you helped me once again

Comment: what was the need of returning 1 here `printf("parenthesis are balanced ");`
                                                               `return 1;`

Comment: what if i will not return this 1 from here or return zero or -1 from here?